# space between rows in a table antd

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, antd

I know this question has many answers, I tried to apply them in ant design but  I couldn't find any way to solve it.

Is there a known way to add space between rows in a table using antd table?

any suggestion would be helpful
thank you

Answer (score 5):

`.ant-table table { border-spacing: 0 10px; }`

Answer (score 0):

I think its not intended to add gutter in tablerows in ant-design. Consider building a grid instead of a table and then add e.g. `<Row gutter={3}>` to it. For the very first row you could assign a className that makes it look like a table header.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like `border-spacing: 0 8px;`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<Space size={size}/>`

size is the way to put distance between elements, the documentation - https://ant.design/components/space/

if you add align, direction - it will suit every need you have